# Sphinx table lookup table on the basis of other

Tags: php, mysql, sphinx

Whether there is an opportunity to look for coincidence according to the table 'Tbl1.PrepStringCustom' comparing the field to all row from other table 'Tbl2.PrepName'.

```
LOOP..
select drug from ix_tovar WHERE MATCH('@PrepStringCustom Tbl2.PrepName')
```

whether there is a way?

Answer (score 0):

Not directly. Would do the loop in the application.

Technically it would be possble with **SphinxSE**, and a MySQL subquery. But its still just a loop (just that mysql-server does the looping, and running the sphinx query for each row)

Or in general could make single Sphinx index, that contains data from **both** tables, and do the query that way. use a 'JOIN' in the sql_query, to create a combined index. BUt may need some logic changes to make it functional.